# why won't the view options for the attribute table under "data; existing file" window not display with Trimble GeoXT?

Tags: trimble

I'm using the Trimble GeoXT and TerraSync version 5.3.

I'm in TerraSync under Data -> Existing File -> and chose a shapefile to open up and view. It immediately displays the attribute table, however, the only field displayed is "distance". When navigating to "options" -> "view", it will let me click on any of the other options including, number, name, label 1, label 2, update, and filter,  as if it were to put a check mark next to it and display that field in the attribute table but it does not!

I know everything displays and all of my data is associated in map view when I click on the features. It just will not display the other attributes in the table. It is not just this one shapefile either, no matter what file I choose to open it displays the table the same.

It only started doing this when I just recently opened the shapefile and was curious with how things displayed in the attribute table so I navigated to options -> view, and un-checked everything except "distance" just to see what it would do. Now it will not let me re-check them.

I've tried a soft and hard reset.

Comment: How did you get your shapefiles onto the Geo XT?  Did you use the File Transfer utility in Pathfinder Office?  You might try removing the shapefiles and then transferring them again.

Comment: Drew, yes I did use the transfer utility in PO and I have removed the files and transferred them back, nothing unfortunately.